# Outlook 2003 to 2010 changed number of pages to print

Tags: html, printing, outlook, ms-office

I was receiving and printing emails from the customer. All emails fit perfectly well on one page when printed. Suddently they started to span 3 pages which is not good for filing.

Client says that they recently changed from MS Office 2003 to MS Office 2010, but no changes were made to the actual email layout.

I check emails before and after. I use MS Office 2010.

Exported before and after emails into MS word - both span 3 pages on print preview.

Saved as html file - both span 3 pages on print preview.

Saved as msg files - and here is the difference :

- old spans 1 page
- new one spans 3 pages on print preview.

When I look at the files in the editor I can see that the generator for old ones is **MSHTML 8.00.6001.18854** and for new one is **Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)**.

The question is: Is there any way new email format in this situation can be changed to print it on 1 page? Please note it is not allowed to change the actual email layout.

Comment: This is a quite general problem so why downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that original message was using html page as a template.

This is a generic problem related to [HTML rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook#HTML_rendering).

So in case of Outlook 2003 Internet Explorer is used, in Outlook 2010 it is Microsoft Word 2010. Wikipedia link says "This means HTML and CSS items not handled by Word are no longer supported. On the other hand, HTML messages composed in Word look as they appeared to the author. This affects publishing newsletters and reports, because they frequently use intricate HTML and CSS to form their layout. For example, forms can no longer be embedded in email."

As a workaround we recommended the client to save html template page as "Webpage, HTML only" format instead of "Webpage, complete" before sending it.